# Unsupported segment type returned on GraphAPI calendarGroup

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Existing working code has now suddenly started failing.  It makes a call to calendarGroup to get the primary calendar group.  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarGroup"

This now has started returning an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unsupported segment type.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "288458d6-6a4a-4879-9bd9-512afc2ed2dd",
        "date": "2016-02-18T13:54:15"
    }
  }
}
```

This can also be easily reproduced by making the above call using their "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarGroup" test site.

The graph.microsoft.io Documentation states:
Get calendarGroup

A user's default calendarGroup.
GET /me/calendarGroup

Anyone from microsoft care to respond?

Comment: because I was not trusted to have more than 2 links in a post.  Here is the direct link to the documentation of graphApi endpoint. [link](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendargroup_get)

Comment: GitHub [issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/124) created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the official response from Microsoft is to remove a documented feature from their production version of the API.  See the linked github [issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/124) for the removal of the feature's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the navigation property is calendarGroups and not calendarGroup (Refer to metadata at https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata or documentation at http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendargroups). Please try the request as https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarGroups.

Comment: The docs here still reflect that /me/calendarGroup will get the user's default calendarGroup:  http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendargroup_get

Comment: and that it was working previously.  And this is not the beta interface and thus should not have stuff like this removed! Short of this call there is no sure way to get the default CalendarGroup entity.  Yes you can take the first entry from the CalendarGroups, but how can you say that it will always be the default group?